# List/Collection blocked until its filled

Tags: c#, multithreading, semaphore

I am trying to achieve something easy to describe, but I cannot find how.

I want to be blocked until a list has at least one element. Let's say we have two workers.

```
Collection c;
```

Worker 1:

```
while(true) {
  var element = c.waitOneElement();
  // Do some stuff with element
}
```

Worker 2:

```
// Do some slow stuff
c.Add(element);
```

This could be done using semaphores, but I'm wondering if there is a built-in class that allows that kind of stuff.

Thanks

Edit: Alternatively, I could map a callback to a "Element added" event, but I don't think it exists.

Comment: Hi, if you use an observable collection you are done, your callback gets called when the collection changes and you do something only if at least 1 element is present. I would avoid locking and semaphoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read about such collections here http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_Concurrent_Collections

and heres a code snippet from that page you might like

```
   public class PCQueue : IDisposable
    {
      BlockingCollection<Action> _taskQ = new BlockingCollection<Action>(); 
      public PCQueue (int workerCount)
      {
        // Create and start a separate Task for each consumer:
        for (int i = 0; i < workerCount; i++)
          Task.Factory.StartNew (Consume);
      }

      public void Dispose() { _taskQ.CompleteAdding(); }

      public void EnqueueTask (Action action) { _taskQ.Add (action); }

      void Consume()
      {
        // This sequence that we’re enumerating will block when no elements
        // are available and will end when CompleteAdding is called. 
        foreach (Action action in _taskQ.GetConsumingEnumerable())
          action();     // Perform task.
      }
    }
```

Notice that Consume method blocks until theres an item in collection.

Answer (score 1):

With .Net 4 you got the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx). With that you can find the [System.Collections.Concurrent Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx). Here you'll find some collections which are capable for what you're trying to do.

Maybe you should also take a look into the document [Patterns for Parallel Programming: Understanding and Applying Parallel Patterns with the .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=86b3d32b-ad26-4bb8-a3ae-c1637026c3ee&displaylang=en).

Comment: Nice answer to a question about parallelism, but IMHO it is the wrong approach for the given scenario